# Search hashmap for key and print certain values

Tags: java

I have a program where I want to input a fake stock symbol, number of shares, and price per share.  I want the user to be able to search the arraylists of stocks, and if a certain stock is found, the LIFO average price of the last 250 stocks bought is displayed.  The user should be able to input a stock more than once, for example

`AAPL 50 99.99`
and
`AAPL 300 50.00`

So if the user bought 50 shares at 99.99 and 300 shares at 50.00, it should average the last 250 bought stocks using the correct prices.

Here is where I am so far, I'm having trouble with searching the hashmap and then displaying the average of that certain stock.

```
package stocks;
import java.util.*;


public class Stocks {
    private String sym;
    private List<Purchase> purchases;

    public Stocks(final String symbol) {
        this.sym = symbol;
        purchases = new ArrayList<Purchase>();
    }

    public void addPurchase(final int amt, final double cost){
        purchases.add(new Purchase(amt,cost));
    }

    public String getSym(){
        return sym;
    }

    public void setSym(){
        this.sym = sym;
    }

    public double getAvg250() {
        int i = 0;
        int total = 0;
        int shares = 0; 
        while (i < purchases.size()) {
            Purchase p = purchases.get(i);
            if (shares + p.getAmt() >= 250) {
                total += (250 - shares) * p.getCost();
                shares = 250;
                break;
            }
            shares += p.getAmt();
            i++; 
        }
        return total * 1.0 / shares;
    }


 class Purchase {
   private int amt;
   private int cost;

   public Purchase(int amt, double cost){

   }

    public int getAmt() {
    return amt;
}

public void setAmt(int amt) {
    this.amt = amt;
}

public int getCost() {
    return cost;
}

public void setCost(int cost) {
    this.cost = cost;
}
 }

public static void main(String[] args) {

       int choice = 0;

       while (choice == 0){
         System.out.println("Enter 1 to input a new stock, or 2 to query a stock's price, 3 to quit: ");
         Scanner sc1 = new Scanner (System.in);
         choice = sc1.nextInt();



         if(choice==1){

           ArrayList<Stocks> StocksList = new ArrayList<Stocks>();
           Scanner sc2 = new Scanner (System.in);
           System.out.println("Please enter the stock symbol: ");
           String sym = sc2.next();
           System.out.println("Please enter the number of shares: ");
           int amt = sc2.nextInt();
           System.out.println("Please enter the price per share: ");
           double cost = sc2.nextDouble();


           Map<String, Stocks> stocks = new HashMap<String, Stocks>();

           Stocks s = stocks.get(sym);
           if (s == null) {
               s = new Stocks(sym);
               stocks.put(sym, s);
           }
           s.addPurchase(amt, cost);
           StocksList.add(s);


         }
         choice = 0;

         if (choice == 2){
             Scanner sc3 = new Scanner (System.in);
             System.out.println("Please enter the symbol of the stock you wish to see: ");
             String search = sc3.next();

         }


         if(choice==3){
           System.exit(0);
         }
         }
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over the HashMap you can do below. Thouhg I am not clear about your question totally

```
Map<String, Stocks> stocks = new HashMap<String, Stocks>();
for (Object key : stocks.keySet()) {
System.out.println("Key : " + key.toString() + " Value : "
        + stocks.get(key));
}
```

Or you can do

```
Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
}
```

**UPDATE**

you can do something like below

```
Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        if( pairs.getKey() != null && pairs.getKey().equals(sym)) {
            pairs.getValue() // this is the cost for share. write logic here to find the last 259 shares and calculate avg
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want the user to input a stock symbol and then it will search the hashmap and print the average of the last 250 shares bought for that stock.

Comment: Whenever I input 2 into the console, the program terminates without any errors.

Comment: Please debug it. I am sure you are using eclipse or netbeans or some other IDE. Please debug. We can only suggest buddy you have to code and give us exact issue.

Comment: `pairs.getValue()  // this is the cost for share. write logic here to find the last 259 shares and calculate avg`

Can you please explain this line to me?

Comment: in this line you will get the stock price for a specific symbol. Then you can write your own logic to calculate the average of that stock.